# Is it possible to write Windows/Linux/MacOS-specific code in Flutter?

Tags: linux, windows, macos, flutter, dart

With `flutter-desktop-embedding`, we are now able to build apps to desktop environments. However, most of the plugins won't work, because they aren't written to these platforms yet. Is there a way to use platform channels to write platform-specific code for the desktop environments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are `MethodChannel` APIs for all three platforms, although Windows and Linux APIs are still subject to change. See https://flutter.dev/desktop#plugins-1 for more information, and the `flutter-desktop-embedding` repository for examples.